# Changing mail configuration in runtime

Tags: spring, email, grails

I've just started to investigate grails framework and first task I'm trying to resolve is sending email. Basic tutorial and community answers provided lot of information for quick start, and yes I've created simple app with possibility to send email. But, next point of my investigation was changing mail configuration in runtime. So, first my configuration in `Config.grovy` was

```
grails {
    mail {
        host = ""
        port = 0
        username = ""
        password = ""
        props = [""]
    }
}
```

with values, and all worked corectlly, after that I've tried to re-config it 
like that

```
grailsApplication.config.grails.mail.host = "smtp.gmail.com"
grailsApplication.config.grails.mail.port = 465
grailsApplication.config.grails.mail.username = ""
```

from **controller**, and found that mail is sending from old adress, after debugs I've found that there are auto-wired instances in mail plugins like `mailSender` and one obvious solution is recreate `mailSender` and re-set it, but judging to Spring singleton policy it will be hard solution, so, My question Are there possibilities to re-configure mail in runtime without class-reloading ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the expected behavior is one of the [TODO](http://grails.org/plugin/mail) items for the plugin.

Comment: 2dmahapato, yes you are right , so, will wait implementation of this feature, in current test project will use my solution, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed using re-init `mailsender` instance but waiting for other solutions, Thanks

```
mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com")
mailSender.setPort(465)
mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(new Properties() {
    {
        put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    }
})
```

Comment: Did you noticed about other solutions?

Comment: May this cause problems if concurrent problems if using in multithreading environment?

Comment: @Sergii Zagriichuk where did you re-init the mailSender? Was it in your service before sending the mail?

Comment: How to re-init mailsender? please show code.

Answer (score 0):

try following way

sendMail {

```
        mailSender.username = 'abc@gmail.com'
        mailSender.password = "pwd"

        to "nagaraj.s@hotmail.com"
        subject "Hi"
        message "Hi"     
    }
```

Comment: Did you forget some `=` ?